# Filtering bad data when counting steps with iPhone accelerometer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I found this code for counting the user's footsteps, but it is not working correctly. It is not showing the exact results.

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
    const float violence = 1.2;
    static BOOL beenhere;
    BOOL shake = FALSE;
    if (beenhere) return;
    beenhere = TRUE;
    if (acceleration.x > violence || acceleration.x < (-1* violence))
       shake = TRUE;
    if (acceleration.y > violence || acceleration.y < (-1* violence))
       shake = TRUE;
    if (acceleration.z > violence || acceleration.z < (-1* violence))
       shake = TRUE;
    if (shake) {
       steps=steps+1;
     }
  beenhere = false;
}
```

It is detecting false steps also. How can I remove the false steps by appliyng filters?

I've been looking for information for several days, and found some here: http://www.analog.com/library/analogDialogue/archives/41-03/pedometer.html, but I'm having trouble applying it.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to get the magnitude of the acceleration vector instead of testing x, or y, or z. Why don't you plot the data and see where it's going wrong? For example, keep an array of acceleration vector magnitudes, and mark where they trigger steps. Something like this:

```
typedef struct accelData {
    float mag;
    BOOL causedStep;
} accelData;
accelData gAcceleration[kMaxDataPoints];
int i = 0;
-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
    const float violence = 1.2;
    float magnitudeOfAcceleration = sqrt (acceleration.x*acceleration.x + acceleration.y * acceleration.y + acceleration.z * acceleration.z);
    BOOL shake = magnitudeOfAcceleration > violence;
    gAcceleration[i].mag = magnitudeOfAcceleration;
    if (shake)
    {
        steps++;
        gAcceleration[i].causedStep = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        gAcceleration[i].causedStep = NO;
    }
}
```

Once you have this data you might be able to analyze it and see what's causing the false recording of steps. Maybe you need to low-pass filter the data to reduce noise or something like that.